# как добавить gitignore в n количество веток одновременно

Tags: git, gitignore

имеется проект с n количеством веток, нужно в каждую ветку добавить gitignore, есть ли какой то способ как это сделать не переключаясь по каждой ветке и не добавляя его в ручную?

Comment: «не переключаясь» — никак. «не добавляя вручную» — запросто: cherry-pick — ваш друг.

Answer (score -1):

Каждый коммит в git - состояние всего репозитория, его слепок. Ветка - указатель на цепочку коммитов.
Если есть основная ветка, master, и несколько feature веток, то в этих ветках есть коммиты, которых нет в master. Но все коммиты, которые есть в master, вполне могут быть в feature ветке.

Поэтому в качестве решения можно сделать коммит в master и подлить master в feature ветки. Таким образом, нужные изменения появятся в feature ветках.

Обратите внимание, что если файл сначала был закоммичен в репозиторий, а потом в gitignore добавилась настройка игнорировать этот файл, он всё равно останется в репозитории, пока его вручную не удалить.